# Proper exception handling on closing file read/write operations

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, bufferedreader

What i want is to reduce exceptions to be thrown from a method.
As you can see i have an inner try catch in the outer catch block to avoid the exception be thrown.
Is this the normal way to do this or are there better (more elegant) ways?
Or is this approach completely false and i should just throw the exception?

```
public static String readText(String filename) {        
    String text = "";
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = null;
        while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ){
            text += line;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(br != null)
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
    return text;
}
```

Comment: That's ok in Java-6, but in Java-7 or later there are better alternatives. Btw, do not concatenate the strings in the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd go for a more modern approach with either `Files.readAllLines();` or `Files.lines();`.

Then all you need to handle is an IOException and the resources are cleaned up for you automatically.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to be more concise in what you want to do:

1. Use a Java 7 feature to catch multiple exceptions in one catch:

   ```
   try {...} catch(FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {...}
   ```
2. Use a Java 7 feature called try-with-resources so you can ommit the finally:

   ```
   try (BufferedReader br =
       new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
   }
   ```

In regards to throwing the exceptions or not is a design choice:

- Do I want to signal errors to the upper layer?
- Can I handle the error on the upper level?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 7 or later you can use try with resource.

```
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    String line = null;
    while( (line = br.readLine()) != null ){
        text += line;
    }
}
```